# Is there an extension of a function field of degree $n$ for every $n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Consider the field of formal Laurent series $\mathbb{C}((t))$, let $X$ be a curve defined over that field, and let $K$ be the field of functions of $X$. Given an integer $n \ge 2$, does there exist an extension of $K$ of degree $n$?

Also, what is a good reference for this material?

Answer (score 0):

This field has negative powers of the variable $t$, but not fractional powers. So $\mathbf{C}((t^{1/n}))$ (I think this is called Puiseux series)  should provide degree $n$ extension you are looking for.

Comment: To my perception, the question literally is asking about curves over _scalars_ $\mathbb C((t))$, so extension of the scalars is not quite to the point... ?

Comment: Is it the case the function field of a curve over $\mathbb{C}((t))$ can be thought of as $\mathbb{C}((t))(s)$ for some indeterminate $s$, and then $\mathbb{C}((t^{1/n}))(s)$ is an extension of degree $n$?

Comment: Hello? Does anyone have any suggestions? 